# How to find the correct this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the images `height` and `width` before they load and set them via `js`, I am running the following:

```
      $("img").each(function() {
        var mySizes = $(this);
        getImageSize($("img"), function(width, height){
          mySizes.width(width).height(height);
        });
      });
      function getImageSize(img, callback) {
        var $img = $(img);
        var wait = setInterval(function() {
          var w = $img[0].naturalWidth,
              h = $img[0].naturalHeight;
          if (w && h) {
              clearInterval(wait);
              callback.apply(this, [w, h]);
            }
        }, 30);
      }
    });
```

But I am getting confused on using `this` and the same sizes seems to be applied to all

Comment: `getImageSize($("img")` you are selecting the images again use: `getImageSize(mySizes , ...`

Comment: you're not even using `this`, so it doesn't matter what you pass to it in this case. in fact you don't even need the `call` function, just call `callback(w, h)`

Comment: @Occam'sRazor the this issue is resolved, but I'm interested in your approach, could you place it into an answer? Thanks

Comment: my comment was not related to the problem, it's not an answer it's just a comment on some pointless code you've got, and the fact that the problem has nothing to do with the "correct this" as your title suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing in `$('img')` to your `getImageSize()` function. That would get **all** images in the document. You then use `$img[0]`, so you'll be applying the size to the first image out of all images.

Instead, you want to pass `this` to `getImageSize()`:

```
$("img").each(function() {
  var mySizes = $(this);
  getImageSize(this, function(width, height) {
    mySizes.width(width).height(height);
  });
});
```

That will mean that you will only pass in the current image you are processing. `each()` will get called once for each image on the page, and you'll process them one at a time.

You could also use `mySizes` instead of `this` there, but since you wrap it up in `$()` in your other function anyways, `mySizes` is redundant. I would just ditch that variable.

Comment: ok yes, actually as per the comment , I should use `getImageSize(mySizes , ` but yes, you are correct

Comment: If it's the answer, please mark it as the correct answer by hitting the check mark.